# No audio on HP pavilion gaming 15

Tags: drivers, sound, output

Warning: I'm totally new and don't know what I'm talking about, please be easy

I have this old HP laptop that I'm trying to put Ubuntu on. I already deleted windows but before I did, the audio and everything else worked fine.

In my sound settings, the output device has only "Dummy Output" as an option. No internal speaker options, and if I install headphones via the aux port there is no indication that anything has happened at all.

When I type "lspci" into terminal the only "Audio Device" is 'Nvidia corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)"

I've been following every guide I can find on the topic but it have accomplished absolutely nothing.

Please if you have any suggestions, I would be very grateful.